# PHP one time expire link

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want a Url Like www.something.com/Somenumber/index.html

example www.google.com/101521145/index.html

means i want a random number before required page

is it possible using PHP and Sql

Comment: It makes not much sense on a site like Stackoverflow to ask if something is possible. Most likely the answer just is *"Yes."* or *"Probably maybe."* or the well known *"It depends."*. Which is most likely not what you wanted to ask for. Please edit and improve your question, here is some help for that: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If Randomness is all you need then :

```
<?php

   $time = round( microtime( true ) * 1000 ); //microtime returns the current microseconds of you server

   echo $time;
?>
```

Comment: suppose take two pages 'index.php'  ,'downloads.php' if we redirect client from index.php to downloads.php by using some logic suppose client redirects from index.php to ./185451/downloads.php . i want to use a random directory before downloads page which would expires in some time how it is possible